# Notepad++ Regex to find group of lines with condition

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

Given this example text:

```
<abr:rules>
<abr:ruleTypeDefinition>
<abr:code>ABB</abr:code>
<abr:ownership>
<abr:owner organization="NT" application="DCS" subapplication="FM"/>
...lines...
...........
</abr:rules>
<abr:rules>
<abr:ruleTypeDefinition>
<abr:code>ADE</abr:code>
<abr:ownership>
<abr:owner organization="NT" application="DCS" subapplication="CM"/>
...lines...
...........
</abr:rules> (end of group)
```

I would like to find and remove all that goes from `<abr:rules>` to `</abr:rules>` with the condition that `subapplication IS NOT "CM"`. Organization and application are the same, `<abr:code>` it's any string.

What I tried so far is

```
<abr:rules>\n<abr:ruleTypeDefinition>\n<abr:code>[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}<\/abr:code>\n<abr:ownership>\n<.*"(FM|PSD|SSC)"\/>\n(?s).*?\n<\/abr:rules>\n
```

which works but only because I know the other subapplication names.

Is there any way to do it with Regex only ?

Comment: Why don't you use Python and an XPath query (for example) instead of an editor that isn't designed for your task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following find and replace:

**Find:**

```
<abr:rules>((?!subapplication=).)*subapplication="(?!CM")[^"]+"((?!</abr:rules>).)*</abr:rules>
```

**Replace:**

```
(empty string)
```

### Demo

**Note:** The above pattern will only work if you enable dot in Notepad++ to match newlines.  If you don't want to do that, then you may use `[\S\s]` instead of dot.

Comment: I like your solution but it's matching 'CM' groups as well. I will post a bigger sample for testing

Comment: @farbiondriven I fixed it by using a tempered dot which can't jump over the ending tag to the next group.

Comment: Sorry Man, still it's getting groups with CM as well.

Comment: @farbiondriven I now use a tempered dot everywhere.

Comment: Bingo !! Working like a charm ! I only needed to put a \n at the end to avoid it leaving an empty line.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use regex for xml, you can read why here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3763374

Instead you can use some parser like [Xpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

Comment: True, for this specific case xml parser would have been simpler. The accepted answer can be applied for any text.

Comment: I won't upvote or downvote your answer because you are right, but: 1) It should be posted as a comment (since it isn't really an answer, more an advice), 2) even if the linked question has many upvotes, the accepted answer is more a joke than an useful answer, 3) XPath isn't a parser, it's a query language.